# Can't access tweet using requests library in Windows

Tags: python, windows, twitter, python-requests

**From Linux Terminal it is working fine , Error Comes in only Windows**

I **can get tweet** using the request library on my python interpreter in terminal but the request library doesn't respond when using in my code

**I am sure that the error** is in fetching twitter link from loop because in one of the function I am fetching resource from [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/ip) to confirm whether proxies and all other things are working and its working fine.

```
def getTweet():
    response = sendGet(twitterUrl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    # For parsing the first tweet
    tweet = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "js-tweet-text"})[tweetNumberFromTopRecent].contents[0]
    print tweet
    return tweet
```

The **sendGet** Function:

```
def sendGet(Url):
    response = requests.get(url=Url, proxies=proxy)
    return response
```

The **Function** calling it is:

```
while True:
    try:
        if getTweet() == '':
            break  # 1 is the value against terminate command
except:
    sleep_for = random.randrange(1, 10)
    time.sleep(sleep_for)  # 1 - 10 seconds wait time
    pass
```

This is what I am getting when logging requests:

```
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.twitter.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.twitter.com
```